# How to save common \addplot options in a variable. [Software Engineering]

Tags: pgfplots

In the following figure, the are three points each of them has common options `\addplot` like `fill=blue, mark=*, thick, only marks, mark size=4pt, point meta=explicit symbolic`, and have some options that distinguish each point like `color=blue`. When I try to edit some common options I have to repeat the edit for every point because of the code duplication.

Is there a way which enables me to store the common options in a variable so that the  duplication is eliminated.
Something like that `\addplot [unique1=value1, \commonFeaturesVariable] { ...`

I found that I can make a global default settings but I don't want that because it will corrupt the figures in the same document that depend on the original default options.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    enlarge x limits=0.1,
    nodes near coords,
]
    \addplot[color=blue, fill=blue, mark=*, thick, only marks, mark size=4pt, point meta=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
        (1, 4)
        };

    \addplot[color=red, fill=red, mark=*, thick, only marks, mark size=4pt, point meta=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (2, 9)
            };

    \addplot[color=brown, fill=brown, mark=*, thick, only marks, mark size=4pt, point meta=explicit symbolic]
        coordinates {
            (3, 7)
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use PGF/Ti*k*Z/pgfplots you have already loaded the `pgfkeys` package. You can use it to define a style:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{%
  myaddplot/.style = {%
    mark=*,
    only marks,
    mark size=4pt,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    enlarge x limits=0.1,
    nodes near coords,
]
    \addplot[color=blue, fill=blue, myaddplot]
        coordinates {
        (1, 4)
        };

    \addplot[color=red, fill=red, myaddplot]
        coordinates {
            (2, 9)
            };

    \addplot[color=brown, fill=brown, myaddplot]
        coordinates {
            (3, 7)
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above will define a global style `myaddplot` which can be used after it was defined.

As Mr. marmot said in the comments, you can omit `fill=<color>` here if you will always want the draw and fill color the same because you specify the `mark = *`. Also, if you will use the same `fill` and `color`, then `thick` will also have no effect because you are plotting `only marks`.

If you want different colors, though, you can make your style take arguments:

```
\pgfplotsset{%
  myaddplot/.style args = {#1/#2}{%
    mark=*,
    only marks,
    mark size=4pt,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    color=#1,
    fill=#2,
  }
}
```

then use as:

```
\addplot[myaddplot=blue/blue]
    coordinates {
    (1, 4)
    };
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not zoom in enough to see that. Sorry!

Comment: @marmot No problem ;)